# About alternative magnetic effect on porcelain (for induction furnace purposes)

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, ceramics

I am trying to use the Induction furnace mechanism (like described via [this video](https://youtu.be/EujaZ_mNt7g)), for heating part of [the Muffle furnace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muffle_furnace), as one [dental porcelain furnace](https://m.alibaba.com/amp/showroom/dental-porcelain-furnace.html) prototype.

So, my plan is to put [copper coil](https://www.google.com/search?q=celonoid%20induction%20heater&client=ms-android-om-lge&prmd=ivsn&sxsrf=ALeKk029PA3Czfd3I5m1_uMpxBAaPLv8SQ:1606562453349&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC5tzCj6XtAhV1HjQIHbByDIkQ_AUoAXoECAMQAQ&biw=360&bih=512&dpr=2#imgrc=31bAV-pEw6o37M&imgdii=BkziDn8TYXv7KM) with frequency around 10 ~ 4000 HZ, and placing some iron bar inside the ceramic container (one sample shown below!):

[image]

.

I have googled the [induction muffle furnace](https://www.google.com/search?q=induction%20muffle%20furnace&oq=induction%20muffle%20furnace&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j69i61.1955j0j9&client=ms-android-om-lge&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), and find only [one patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2912553A/en) by this topic (you can see below):

[image]

So, I am in doubt that some part of this project must be wrong. So, I asked here about the effect of changing the magnetic field on the characteristics of [dental porcelain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_porcelain), if that effect were too much and create some deformation via dental porcelain coating, this prototype would not be proper for this purpose.

As I am not familiar with chemical terms and ..., If possible, suggest some proper tag to faster finding the effect of the alternative magnetic on the dental porcelain coating.

**Update:**

For clarifying question it must be said:

> induction furnace mechanism are working fine, and for creating high
> temperature the plan have had some additional metal bar to become hot
> (based of induction mechanism), and create the desired heating for
> melting the porcelain coating. But my question is about the effects of
> alternative magnetic fields on desired characteristics of porcelain
> (target).

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

On reason you don't see much information is that your plan will not work. The copper wire will get hot by resistance and conduction and at some temperature it will react with the refractory = fail. Copper has essentially no use as a heating element because the oxide spalls off after each heat cycle. Use Nichrome wire ( this alloy family has a few different names ). However , as I understand induction heating it needs an conductive target. I am guessing your dental porcelain has poor electric conductivity , so will not heat by induction.

Comment: thanks for you answer, the induction furnace mechanism are working fine, and for creating high temperature the plan have had some additional metal bar to become hot (based of induction mechanism), and create the desired heating for melting the porcelain coating. But my question is about the effects of alternative magnetic fields on desired characteristics of porcelain (target).

Comment: So you are heating the porcelain by conduction of heat from a metal bar heated by induction . Difficult for me to see any advantage.

Comment: Thanks, but i asked about chemical engineering to be more aware about the special changes made by magnetic alternative fields on porcelain materials.